# How to visualize actual underlying computation code?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm studying Tensorflow.

During some tests, I want to see the actual code of the Tensorflow computation. Actually, after defining the graph, it makes the session which it will go to calculate.

However, I cannot figure out the place where the actual computation (e.g., a*b, a+b, e^a, etc.) is. I'm expecting the code to be implemented in C++. For example, I'd like to see the code of the `tanh` operation, however, I can't find it, even after having looked into `cwise_op_tanh.cc` file.

Can I get some advice?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Actually, after defining the graph, it makes the session which it will go to calculate."?

Comment: I mean that before going to training, we define the graph and make the tf.Session(). Then the graph will be executed(computation will executed) according to the output which we want to get. Isn't right?

Comment: According to the output we want to get? You mean according to the values we pass to the parameters of the `run` method of the session object?

Comment: Yap... Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Well, but why exactly did you mention the session and graph?

Comment: Actually I was working on watching all process of tensorflow training one by one, so I mentioned about session and graph. However I think that it is unnecessary to mentioning session and graph as you said. My point is that I want to get some advice where I can see the code of actual computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The architecture for operations is explained in the [documentation on adding a new op (and related)](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op). It is flexible, for automated code generation, so confusing at first.

When looking for an implementation, I usually search for the `REGISTER_OP` string in the source code. This macro registers an operation to the TensorFlow engine (see the aformentioned link for detail---it is more involved). The macro should give all "pointers" to know where to look at. It can be complicated when there is an implementation per device type (CPU, GPU, special GPUs), or ramifications/compositions.

For example, on `tanh`, I look for `tanh`, or it seems the convention is `Tanh`, in the source code:

```
> cd /path/to/tensorflow/source
> grep -R REGISTER_OP tensorflow | grep -i tanh
tensorflow/core/ops/math_grad.cc:REGISTER_OP_GRADIENT("Tanh", TanhGrad);
tensorflow/core/ops/math_grad.cc:REGISTER_OP_GRADIENT("Atanh", AtanhGrad);
tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc:REGISTER_OP("Tanh").UNARY_COMPLEX();
tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc:REGISTER_OP("Atanh").UNARY_COMPLEX();
tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc:REGISTER_OP("TanhGrad").UNARY_GRADIENT_COMPLEX();
tensorflow/core/ops/nn_ops.cc:REGISTER_OP("_MklTanh")
tensorflow/core/ops/nn_ops.cc:REGISTER_OP("_MklTanhGrad")
```

The result: `tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc:REGISTER_OP("Tanh").UNARY_COMPLEX();` looks like what we are looking for. This leads to a `UNARY_COMPLEX` macro definition:

```
#define UNARY_COMPLEX()                                                  \
  Input("x: T")                                                          \
      .Output("y: T")                                                    \
      .Attr("T: {half, bfloat16, float, double, complex64, complex128}") \
      .SetShapeFn(shape_inference::UnchangedShape)
```

The actual implementation is often a function wrapped into the `SetShapeFn` call. But the implementation is also often delegated, like here. We know `tanh` is a coefficient-wise operation, and that, with a bit more search, `tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_op_tanh.cc` and `tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_op_gpu_tanh.cu.cc` are the only kernels registering `tanh`. But this time these files use "utilities" like `REGISTER5` for more compact boiler-plate registrations. For example we can find:

```
REGISTER5(UnaryOp, CPU, "Tanh", functor::tanh, float, Eigen::half, double,
      complex64, complex128);
```

Which ends up calling `REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER`---the [partner](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) of `REGISTER_OP`---to register the actual implementation for the registered operation. Looking through the code, the implementation is `functor::tanh`, which is a wrapper for the actual implementation, usually delegated to the Eigen linear algebra library. And Eigen may sometimes itself [delegate](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__CoeffwiseMathFunctions.html) some operations even further.

Notes:

- One way to perhaps speed up search is to use `REGISTER` instead of `REGISTER_OP` as a search pattern. That would return way more results, though.
- All code extracts come from the current TensorFlow version (commit `ac8e67399d75edce6a9f94afaa2adb577035966e`). Beware the code changes often.
- Tensorflow is migrating to a more abstract architecture called [XLA](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/), for a range or reasons. So the above explanation will become obsolete.